# Deleting line vertices inside polygon using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, point-in-polygon, vertices

Is there a way to automatically delete vertices in line features using a polygon file in ArcGIS so that it wouldn't cut up the line but just straightens the line inside the polygon?

The lines are lines and the box represents a polygon that covers them. I want to delete line vertices that are inside the polygon so the line would be straight inside the polygon boundary like on the illustration.

I use ArcGIS 10.1 but have access to other software also if something offers the solution.

[image: Lines are lines, box is polygon.]

Comment: As a new user please take the [Tour].  Would you be able to [edit] your question to include a picture of your before and after, please?

Comment: Do you have an Advanced license? The geoprocessing tools available will help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's where an Advanced license will be useful.

1. Use the [Clip](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/clip.htm) tool to clip the "**Line**" feature class (FC) by the "**Polygon**" FC. Name the output "**Lines_Inside**".
2. Use the [Erase](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/erase.htm) tool to do the opposite, and erase the lines that fall inside the polygons. Name the output "**Lines_Outside**".
3. For the "**Lines_Inside**" FC, use the [Feature Vertices to Points](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/feature-vertices-to-points.htm) tool specifying the "BOTH_ENDS" option to create a point for the start and end node of each line. Create a field called "*LineID*" that uniquely identifies which line each start and end point belonged to (you can do this using a Join or Spatial Join or Selection or otherwise). Unfortunately I don't have an Advanced license in front of me to test the exact steps.
4. Use the [Points to Line](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/points-to-line.htm) tool on your results from Step #3 to create ***straight-line*** segments out of the start and end points of the original "**Lines_Inside**" FC. You will have to specify your "*LineID*" field you created in Step #3 for the "Line_Field" parameter.
5. Merge/Append/Data Load the results of Step #4 to your "**Lines_Outside**" FC to get the two FCs back together.
6. Use the [Unsplit Line](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/unsplit-line.htm) tool or [Dissolve](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) tool to merge the parts back together into single lines. You may have to do a [Spatial Join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) to get the attributes back in the middle segments (which you generated) prior to running the tools.

Hope this helps. I can add screenshots when I'm able to access an Advanced license if you need them. The only other solution I can think of if these steps don't work would be to mess with the list of vertices in the [arcpy.array](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/array.htm) object for each [arcpy.polyline](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/polyline.htm) in your FC, which would be doable without the Advanced license but significantly harder without some Python skills.

Answer (score 6):

The key is the [`difference`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/geometry.htm#M1_GUID-BC466D06-360C-42BD-B198-DA4139B45F49) method on geometry objects. The following code is far from efficient, since a new update cursor is opened for each polygon. But it has the added benefit of supporting multiple polygons on the same line:

```py
import itertools, arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
line_FC = r'<path to lines>'
poly_FC = r'<path to polygons>'
output = r'<path to result>'

#clone input lines to memory for fast processing
temp = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(line_FC, "in_memory/temp")

polygons = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(poly_FC, arcpy.Geometry())

for poly in polygons:
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(temp, ["SHAPE@"]) as uCursor:
        for line in uCursor:
            line = line[0]
            diff = line.difference(poly)
            #if the two lines are not equal, that means it intersected the polygon
            if not line.equals(diff):
                #the result of geometry.difference() is a multipart line of only those
                #parts that lie outside the polyon
                parts = diff.getPart()

                #if parts is empty that means the line is completely within the polygon
                #i.e., no difference
                if parts:
                    #We'll need to "join" the end of part1 to the beginning of part2
                    #so we'll just flatten the list of lists
                    joined = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(parts))

                    #and create a new polyline object to update the shape
                    poly_trimmed = arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array(joined))
                    uCursor.updateRow([poly_trimmed])

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(temp, output)
```

I haven't tested it with edge cases, but this should get you started.
[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do the same but not create vertex on intersections?