# Deleting polyline vertices coincident with points in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I'm looking to take a shapefile of points and a geodatabase feature class of lines as input and delete the vertices from the lines coincident with the points.

I found a similar question already asked and answered, but dealing with lines and polygons instead of points. Would the method outlined [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167394/deleting-line-vertices-inside-polygon-using-arcpy) by Paul work with points as well? I have never used difference so I don't know how it would work when run on points.

Comment: Have you tried it on a small subset just to see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what the size of your datasets are but lets assume a few thousand features. Another approach would be this using python:

1. Create a list of XY coordinates for all of your points
2. With an update cursor cycle through your polylines. For each polyline explode them into a list of XY coordinates.
3. If any polyline XY coordinates are found in the point XY list then remove them.
4. If any XY's have been removed from the polyline list then rebuild the polyline and update the shape using the update cursor, otherwise skip

You could improve performance be pre-selecting polylines that intersect your points as the cursor will honour selections.